# Fastest way to compute row-wise dot products between two skinny tall matrices in R

Tags: r

Consider A and B are two tall skinny matrices of dimension 10^8 X 5.
i.e.;

```
r=10^8
c=5
A=matrix(runif(r*c,0,1),r,c)
B=matrix(runif(r*c,0,1),r,c)
```

I want to compute dot product of each row of A with the corresponding row of B, i.e.;

```
rowSums(A * B)
```

But it is quite slow and I would like would like to know if there is any faster way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might disappoint you but at R level, this is already the best you can get without writing some C code yourself. The problem is that by doing `rowSums(A * B)`, you are effectively doing

```
C <- A * B
rowSums(C)
```

The first line performs a full scan of three large tall-thin matrices; while the second line performs a full scan of 1 large tall-thin matrix. So altogether, we equivalently scan a tall-thin matrix 4 times (memory intensive).

In fact, for such operation, the optimal algorithm only needs scanning a `n * p` tall-thin matrix twice, by doing **rowwise cross product**:

```
rowsum <- numeric(n)
for j = 1, 2, ... p
  rowsum += A[,i] * B[,i]
```

In this way, we also avoid generating matrix `C`. Note, the above is just a fake code rather than valid R code or even C code. But the idea is clear, and we want to program this in C.

---

An analogy to your situation is the speed difference between `sum(x * y)` and `crossprod(x, y)`, assuming `x` and `y` be large vectors of the same length.

```
x <- runif(1e+7)
y <- runif(1e+7)

system.time(sum(x * y))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.124   0.032   0.158 

system.time(crossprod(x, y))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.036   0.000   0.056
```

In the first case, we scan a long vector 4 times, while in the second case, we only scan it twice.

---

**Relevance in statistical computing**

`rowSums(A * B)` is in fact an efficient evaluation of `diag(tcrossprod(A, B))`, commonly seen in regression computing associated with point-wise prediction variance. For example, in ordinary linear squares regression with thin `Q` matrix from QR factorization of model matrix, the point-wise variance of fitted values are `diag(tcrossprod(Q))`, which is more efficiently computed by `rowSums(Q ^ 2)`. But yet, this is still not the fastest evaluation, for reasons already explained.