# Does the term "vectorization" mean different things in different contexts?

Tags: r, julia, vectorization

Based on what I've read before, vectorization is a form of parallelization known as SIMD. It allows processors to execute the same instruction (such as addition) on an array simultaneously.

However, I got confused when reading [The Relationship between Vectorized and Devectorized Code](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2013/12/22/the-relationship-between-vectorized-and-devectorized-code/) regarding Julia's and R's vectorization performance. The post claims that devectorized Julia code (via loops) is faster than the vectorized code in both Julia and R, because:

> This confuses some people who are not familiar with the internals of
>   R. It is therefore worth noting how one improves the speed of R code.
>   The process of performance improvement is quite simple: one starts
>   with devectorized R code, then replaces it with vectorized R code and
>   then finally implements this vectorized R code in devectorized C code.
>   This last step is unfortunately invisible to many R users, who
>   therefore think of vectorization per se as a mechanism for increasing
>   performance. Vectorization per se does not help make code faster. What
>   makes vectorization in R effective is that it provides a mechanism for
>   moving computations into C, where a hidden layer of devectorization
>   can do its magic.

It claims that R turns vectorized code, written in R, into devectorized code in C. If vectorization is faster (as a form of parallelization), why would R devectorize the code and why is that a plus?

Comment: Further to my answer, you can read the following: [Is the “*apply” family really not vectorized?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28983292/4891738) and [Is R's apply family more than syntactic sugar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2275896/4891738), specially the first. People tried to make it clear what "true vectorization" is in R, but in my opinion, the demonstration is rather ambiguous. It got messier when Arun suddenly threw in an answer about SIMD. So do read my answer first (as well as the links given in my answer).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Vectorization" in R, is a vector processing in R's interpreter's view. Take the function `cumsum` as an example. On entry, R interpreter sees that a vector `x` is passed into this function. However, the work is then passed to C language that R interpreter can not analyze / track. While C is doing work, R is just waiting. By the time that R's interpreter comes back to work, a vector has been processed. So in R's view, it has issued a single instruction but processed a vector. This is an analogy to the concept of SIMD - "single instruction, multiple data".

Not just the `cumsum` function that takes a vector and returns a vector is seen as "vectorization" in R, functions like `sum` that takes a vector and returns a scalar is also a "vectorization".

Simply put: whenever R calls some compiled code for a loop, it is a "vectorization". If you wonder why this kind of "vectorization" is useful, it is because a loop written by a compiled language is faster than a loop written in an interpreted language. The C loop is translated to machine language that a CPU can understand. However, if a CPU wants to execute an R loop, it needs R's interpreter's help to read it, iteration by iteration. This is like, if you know Chinese (the hardest human language), you can respond to someone speaking Chinese to you faster; otherwise, you need a translator to first translator Chinese to you sentence after sentence in English, then you respond in English, and the translator make it back to Chinese sentence by sentence. The effectiveness of communication is largely reduced.

```
x <- runif(1e+7)

## R loop
system.time({
  sumx <- 0
  for (x0 in x) sumx <- sumx + x0
  sumx
  })
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.388   0.000   1.347 

## C loop
system.time(sum(x))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.032   0.000   0.030
```

Be aware that "vectorization" in R is just an **analogy** to SIMD but not a real one. A real SIMD uses CPU's vector registers for computations hence is a true parallel computing via data parallelism. R is not a language where you can program CPU registers; you have to write compiled code or assembly code for that purpose.

R's "vectorization" does not care how a loop written in a compiled language is really executed; after all that is beyond R's interpreter's knowledge. Regarding whether these compiled code will be executed with SIMD, read [Does R leverage SIMD when doing vectorized calculations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37213060/4891738)

---

**More on "vectorization" in R**

I am not a Julia user, but [Bogumił Kamiński](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51683513/4891738) has demonstrated an impressive feature of that language: *loop fusion*. Julia can do this, because, as he points out, *"vectorization in Julia is implemented in Julia", not outside the language*.

This reveals a downside of R's vectorization: speed often comes at a price of memory usage. I am not saying that Julia won't have this problem (as I don't use it, I don't know), but this is definitely true for R.

Here is an example: [Fastest way to compute row-wise dot products between two skinny tall matrices in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40228592/4891738). `rowSums(A * B)` is a "vectorization" in R, as both `"*"` and `rowSums` are coded in C language as a loop. However, R can not fuse them into a single C loop to avoid generating the temporary matrix `C = A * B` into RAM.

Another example is R's recycling rule or any computations relying on such rule. For example, when you add a scalar `a` to a matrix `A` by `A + a`, what really happens is that `a` is first replicated to be a matrix `B` that has the same dimension with `A`, i.e., `B <- matrix(a, nrow(A), ncol(A))`, then an addition between two matrices are calculated: `A + B`. Clearly the generation of the temporary matrix `B` is undesired, but sorry, you can't do it better unless you write your own C function for `A + a` and call it in R. This is described as *"such a fusion is possible only if explicitly implemented"* in [Bogumił Kamiński's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51683513/4891738).

To deal with the memory effects of many temporary results, R has a sophisticated mechanism called "garbage collection". It helps, but memory can still explode if you generate some really big temporary result somewhere in your code. A good example is the function `outer`. I have written many answers using this function, but it is particularly memory-unfriendly.

I might have been off-topic in this edit, as I begin to discuss the side effect of "vectorization". Use it with care.

- Put memory usage in mind; there might be a more memory efficient vectorized implementation. For example, as mentioned in the linked thread on row-wise dot products between two matrices, `c(crossprod(x, y))` is better than `sum(x * y)`.
- Be prepared to use CRAN R packages that have compiled code. If you find existing vectorized functions in R limited to do your task, explore CRAN for possible R packages that can do it. You can ask a question with your coding bottleneck on Stack Overflow, and somebody may point you to the right function in the right package.
- Be happy to write your own compiled code.

Comment: It should also be noted that Julia will apply SIMD as one of the optimizations on its tight loops via LLVM. You can explicitly add SIMD using SIMD.jl or the `@simd` macro to a loop call. This does make the terminology confusing though, so to disambiguate in Julia "R-like vectorization" is called broadcasting and SIMD-vectorization is just called SIMD. I guess that's one of the quirks of being a language both for high level science code and low level fast code :).

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas "R-like vectorization" is called "broadcasting"? Isn't that also aliased with SIMD operation `vbroadcast`?

Comment: Well yes, but most of the time when discussing it at a high level people aren't mentioning the specifics of SIMD, and [broadcast then refers to the dot operators](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6.1/manual/functions/#man-vectorized-1).

Answer (score 8):

I think it is worth to note that the post you are referring to does not cover all current functionality of vectorization in Julia.

The important thing is that vectorization in Julia is implemented in Julia, as opposed to R, where it is implemented outside of the language. This is explained in detail in this post: https://julialang.org/blog/2017/01/moredots.

The consequence of the fact that Julia can perform fusion of any sequence of broadcasted operations into a single loop. In other languages that provide vectorization such a fusion is possible only if explicitly implemented.

In summary:

1. In Julia you can expect that vectorized code is as fast as a loop.
2. If you perform a sequence of vectorized operations then in general you can expect Julia to be faster than R as it can avoid allocation of intermediate results of the computations.

EDIT:

Following the comment of [李哲源](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4891738/%e6%9d%8e%e5%93%b2%e6%ba%90) here is an example showing that Julia is able to avoid any allocations if you want to increase all elements of a vector `x` by `1`:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> x = rand(10^6);

julia> @benchmark ($x .+= 1)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  0 bytes
  allocs estimate:  0
  --------------
  minimum time:     819.230 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      890.610 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        929.659 μs (0.00% GC)
  maximum time:     2.802 ms (0.00% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          5300
  evals/sample:     1
```

In the code `.+=` performs addition in place (adding `$` in front of the expression is only needed for benchmarking, in normal code it would be `x .+= 1`). And we see that no memory allocation was done.

If we compare this to a possible implementation in R:

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> x <- runif(10^6)
> microbenchmark(x <- x + 1)
Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 x <- x + 1 2.205764 2.391911 3.999179 2.599051 5.061874 30.91569   100
```

we can see that it not only saves memory, but also leads to a faster execution of the code.

Comment: I think the following slide http://slides.com/valentinchuravy/julia-parallelism#/1/1 shows best what Julia is doing with your code before it gets executed. And you can see that there are several levels where optimization can happen (and actually happens). So the answer is: yes, Julia is a compiled language that is does numerous optimizations before your code is run, but at the same time you can use it interactively like R and Python as compilation happens on-the-go (you can also precompile Julia code if needed).

Comment: You can find a blog post that discusses exactly this topic here http://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/why-numba-and-cython-are-not-substitutes-for-julia/.