# How to check if any two adjacent elements in a vector are non-zero

Tags: r, vector

I have a list of all possible binary 12-length vectors in R via

```
all_possible_permutations <- expand.grid(replicate(12, 0:1, simplify = FALSE))
```

I'd like to flag all vectors where two non-zero cells are adjacent to one another.

So for instance

```
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 <- Not Flagged
1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 <- Flagged (due to the first 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any binary vector `x`, we can use the following logic to detect existing pattern of two adjacent 1:

```
flag <- function (x) sum(x == 1 & c(diff(x) == 0, FALSE)) > 0

x <- c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
flag(x)
#[1] TRUE

x <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
flag(x)
#[1] FALSE
```

So we can apply this to all columns of your data frame `DF`:

```
sapply(DF, flag)
```

---

As [r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans) commented, this also works:

```
flag <- function (x) any(x == 1 & c(diff(x) == 0, FALSE))
```

Using `sum` gives you a by-product: it tells you the number of matches.

---

Gosh, you want to apply `flag` for every row not every column of `DF`. So I should not use `sapply`. In this case, let's do a full vectorization:

```
MAT <- t(DF)
result <- colSums(MAT == 1 & rbind(diff(MAT) == 0, FALSE)) > 0
table(result)
#FALSE  TRUE 
#  377  3719
```

In this case `colSums` can not be changed to `any`. [The vectorization comes at more memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51682265/4891738), but is probably worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rle` since this is binary ie `0` and `1`s:

```
flag = function(x)any(with(rle(x),lengths[values==1]>1))
```

if non binary, yet you want to check if two adjacent elements are non zero then:

```
flag = function(x)any(with(rle(x>0),lengths[values]>1))
```

which is a generalized case taking into account the binary and non-binary